# Why Am I Getting Failure Delivering Result ResultInfo Using Camera?

Tags: android, camera, nullpointerexception, cursor, uri

I am a noob to android development and I am having trouble returning an image taken by the camera.  My app runs fine when I take a picture vertically/portrait, but when take a picture horizontally/landscape the app crashes with an error that says   Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} . I've adjusted my width & height of my output pic with no success.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

MY CODE

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //check if we are returning from picture selection
        if (requestCode == PICKER) {

            //the returned picture URI
     //       Uri pickedUri = data.getData();

            //declare the bitmap
            Bitmap pic = null;
            //declare the path string
            String imgPath = "";

            //retrieve the string using media data
            String[] medData = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            //query the data
            Cursor picCursor = managedQuery(outputFileUri, medData, null, null, null);
            if(picCursor!=null)
            {
                //get the path string
                int index = picCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                picCursor.moveToFirst();
                imgPath = picCursor.getString(index);
            }
            else
                imgPath = outputFileUri.getPath();

            //if and else handle both choosing from gallery and from file manager

            //if we have a new URI attempt to decode the image bitmap
            if(outputFileUri!=null) {

                //set the width and height we want to use as maximum display
                int targetWidth = 600;
                int targetHeight = 400;

                //sample the incoming image to save on memory resources

                //create bitmap options to calculate and use sample size
                BitmapFactory.Options bmpOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                //first decode image dimensions only - not the image bitmap itself
                bmpOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, bmpOptions);

                //work out what the sample size should be

                //image width and height before sampling
                int currHeight = bmpOptions.outHeight;
                int currWidth = bmpOptions.outWidth;

                //variable to store new sample size
                int sampleSize = 1;

                //calculate the sample size if the existing size is larger than target size
                if (currHeight>targetHeight || currWidth>targetWidth) 
                {
                    //use either width or height
                    if (currWidth>currHeight)
                        sampleSize = Math.round((float)currHeight/(float)targetHeight);
                    else 
                        sampleSize = Math.round((float)currWidth/(float)targetWidth);
                }
                //use the new sample size
                bmpOptions.inSampleSize = sampleSize;

                //now decode the bitmap using sample options
                bmpOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

                //get the file as a bitmap
                pic = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, bmpOptions);

                if(currentPic<=10){                     
                    //pass bitmap to ImageAdapter to add to array
                    imgAdapt.addPic(pic);
                    currentPic++;
                }

                //redraw the gallery thumbnails to reflect the new addition
                picGallery.setAdapter(imgAdapt);

                //display the newly selected image at larger size
                picView.setImageBitmap(pic);
                //scale options
                picView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            }
        }
    }
    //superclass method
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

LOGCAT

```
04-03 08:26:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(15318): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.pickenssurvey/com.example.pickenssurvey.PictureGallery}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 08:26:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3179)
04-03 08:26:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
04-03 08:26:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):    ... 13 more
04-03 08:26:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(15318): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 08:26:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:913)
04-03 08:26:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:305)
04-03 08:26:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):    at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1742)
04-03 08:26:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):    at com.example.pickenssurvey.PictureGallery.onActivityResult(PictureGallery.java:241)
04-03 08:26:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4723)
04-03 08:26:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3175)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your screen orientation changes, your Activity is destroyed and recreated in the new orientation. So any variables that gained a reference during the life of the Activity will no longer refer to anything, and if you then try to access objects they refer to without re-assigning them values, you'll get a NullPointerException.

The method onSaveInstanceState() is used to save temporary data between configuration changes. This creates a Bundle which is passed to onCreate() when the Activity starts up again.

Without any code, I don't know if that's your problem, but it's worth a look.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges for more information (and more accurate information than I've provided, no doubt).

Not mine copied from other post

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to support portrait and landscape views in your app? If not, the problem could possibly be solved by preventing orientation changes. Put following code in your onCreate:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

It will still be possible to change the orientation in the camera intent.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem earlier and didn't see any answers that matched my cause.

The problem was:

1. The Camera takes over
2. The device is rotated while in Camera mode
3. Snap a picture and confirm it
4. The picture is sent back to the activity BUT your Activity/Fragment gets
   destroyed and recreated on screen orientation change 
   including the
   variable that stored your output URI File/String

Solution:

1. Store the output URI in your `onSaveInstanceState` method containing the bundle which is used to recreate the activity
2. Retrieve the file from the Bundle in `onRestoreInstanceState` for activity and `onCreateView` for fragments